# Why was there never a segment for the number one in the Pinball Number Count?

Tags: production, sesame-street

*Pinball Number Count* is an animated segment featured in *Sesame Street*, in which a ball rolls around a pinball machine, during which we hear several counts from one to twelve, as well as call outs of the featured number. The lines, consisting of counting and scatting, are sung by the Pointer Sisters.

The middle segment is unique to each number. There is [a segment for the numbers 2 to 12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinball_Number_Count#List_of_segments), the number 1 being a glaring omission.

**Why is there no segment for 1?**

It seems to have never been created, but why?

---

[An email from the composer, Walt Kraemer](https://mattjon.es/blog/2003/09/a-letter-from-walt-kraemer/), seems to confirm that a segment for one was never created, but does not tell us why.

> [...] there were to be eleven pieces of animation [...]

Comment: Emailing the composer is no longer an option

Comment: I would assume it's because it's a song about counting, and you can't count to one.

Comment: @Valorum The count always goes to twelve.

Comment: I think you can count to one, it’s just too easy to be as educational.

Comment: Oh, wow!  This brings back memories!  It's weird, because it shows the number 1 in each segment when doing the countdown, but doesn't say the number 1 in the jingle.

Comment: In the days when this segment aired, were there any number segments of any kind that used the number 1?  I was watching old Sesame Streets with my kid (before HBO inexplicably removed everything older than season 38) and I can't recall ever seeing a segment about 1, and never an episode "brought to you by the number 1" or any such.

Comment: @Juhasz - there certainly were. Here's [one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BsJRlfjYo9Y) and here's another[one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cJvjYQ0JYJ0)